# Use default arguments in npm scripts

Tags: npm, command-line-arguments, package.json, npm-scripts

I want to use default arguments in npm scripts. After some investigation, I find that

```
//  package.json
...
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "format-check:prettier": "prettier --check ${FILES:-.}",
    ...
  },
...
```

can be used in Linux OS.

When I use `$ FILES=src/api.ts npm run format-check:prettier`, `$FILES` will be `src/api.ts`.

When I use `$ npm run format-check:prettier`, `$FILES` will be default to `.`.

However, I haven't found the way to set the default value in Windows OS. How to set the default parameter in Windows OS?